# How to check for presence of named pipe on the file system

Tags: bash, test, fifo, mkfifo

I tried using the -f flag to test if a named pipe is present

```
if [[ ! -f "$fifo" ]]; then
  echo 'There should be a fifo.lock file in the dir.' > /dev/stderr
  return 0;
fi
```

this check does not seem correct. So perhaps a named-pipe is not a file, but something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `-p` construct to see if the file is of type *named* pipe. It works with the standard test `[` (POSIX compliant) and the extended test operators `[[` ( bash/zsh specific )

```
if [[ -p "$fifo" ]]; then
    printf '%s is a named pipe' "$fifo"
fi
```

From the `man` pages of bash

> `-p` *`file`*
>
> True if *`file`* exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).

or use the `file` command with the `-b` to just print the type information without the filename. The `-b` might not be POSIX compliant

```
if [ $(file -b "$fifo") = "fifo (named pipe)" ]; then
   printf '%s is a named pipe' "$fifo"
fi
```

Without the `-b`, one could do

```
type=$(file "$fifo")
if [ "${type##*: }" = "fifo (named pipe)" ]; then
```